# Wrong encoding when getting a string from MySQL database with C++

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2012, encoding, mfc

I'm writing an MFC app with C++ in Visual Studio 2012. App connects to a MySQL database and shows every row to a List Box.
Words are in Russian, database encoding is cp1251. I've set the same character set using this code:

```
if (!mysql_set_character_set(mysql, "cp1251")) {
    statusBox.SetWindowText((CString)"CP1251 is set for MYSQL.");
}
```

But it doesn't help at all.
I display data using this code:

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL) {
    CString string = (CString)row[1];
    listBox.AddString(string);
}
```

This code also doesn't help:

```
mysql_query(mysql, "set names cp1251");
```

Please help. What should I do to display cyrillic correctly?

Comment: `CString` doesn't know that it should encode strings using CP1251. It probably uses Unicode (depending on your project settings). To convert from DB-encoding (CP1251) to Unicode (UTF-16) call [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx).

Comment: Can you give me an example how I should use it in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When crossing system boundaries that use different character encodings you have to convert between them. In this case, the MySQL database uses CP 1251 while Windows (and `CString`) use UTF-16. The conversion might look like this:

```
#if !defined(_UNICODE)
    #error Unicode configuration required
#endif

CString CPtoUnicode( const char* CPString, UINT CodePage ) {
    CString retValue;
    // Retrieve required string length
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar( CodePage, 0,
                                   CPString, -1,
                                   NULL, 0 );
    if ( len == 0 ) {
        // Error -> return empty string
        return retValue;
    }

    // Allocate CString's internal buffer
    LPWSTR buffer = retValue.GetBuffer( len );
    // Do the conversion
    MultiByteToWideChar( CodePage, 0,
                         CPString, -1,
                         buffer, len );
    // Return control of the buffer back to the CString object
    retValue.ReleaseBuffer();
    return retValue;
}
```

This should be used as follows:

```
while ( ( row = mysql_fetch_row( result ) ) != NULL ) {
    CString string = CPtoUnicode( row[1], 1251 );
    listBox.AddString( string );
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `CString`s built-in conversion support, which requires to set the thread's locale to the source encoding (CP 1251) and use the conversion constructor.